# Parameter's value is null on put method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is the model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;

namespace CollectionsCatalogWebAPI.Models
{
    [Table("User")]
    public class User
    {

        #region attributes

        private Int64 id;
        private String username;
        private String firstName;
        private String middleInitials;
        private String lastName;
        private String password;
        private String gender;
        private String active;

        #endregion

        #region properties

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Int64 Id
        {
            set { this.id = value; }
            get { return this.id; }

        }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public String Username
        {
            set { this.username = value; }
            get { return this.username; }
        }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public String FirstName
        {
            set { this.firstName = value; }
            get { return this.firstName; }
        }

        [StringLength(10)]
        public String MiddleInitials
        {
            set { this.middleInitials = value; }
            get { return this.middleInitials; }
        }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public String LastName
        {
            set { this.lastName = value; }
            get { return this.lastName; }
        }

        [StringLength(64)]
        public String Password
        {
            set { this.password = value; }
            get { return this.password; }
        }

        [StringLength(1)]
        public String Gender
        {
            set { this.gender = value; }
            get { return this.gender; }
        }

        [StringLength(1)]
        public String Active
        {
            set { this.active = value; }
            get { return this.active; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region especifcMethods

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a string representation of this instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns a string representation of this instance.</returns>
        public override String ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.Append("[CollectionsCatalogWebAPI.Models.User:");
            sb.Append(" Username: ");
            sb.Append(this.Username);
            sb.Append(" FirstName: ");
            sb.Append(this.FirstName);
            sb.Append(" MiddleInitials: ");
            sb.Append(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.MiddleInitials) ? "" : this.MiddleInitials);
            sb.Append(" LastName: ");
            sb.Append(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.LastName) ? "" : this.LastName);
            sb.Append(" Gender: ");
            sb.Append(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Gender) ? "" : this.Gender);
            sb.Append(" Active: ");
            sb.Append(String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Active) ? "" : this.Active);
            sb.Append("]");

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And now on controller the two methods GET is ok, but the POST is not working.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using CollectionsCatalogWebAPI.Config;
using CollectionsCatalogWebAPI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CollectionsCatalogWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Users")]
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {

        private readonly CollectionsCatalogContex context;

        public UsersController(CollectionsCatalogContex context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<User> Get()
        {
            return context.UsersModel.ToList<User>();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(User))]
        [ProducesResponseType(404)]
        public IActionResult Get(Int64 id)
        {
            var user = context.UsersModel.Find(id);

            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(user);
        }

        // POST: api/Users
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post(User u)
        {
            context.UsersModel.Add(u);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("Get", new { id = u.Id}, u);
        }
    }
}
```

When I post using Postman the json below I receive an SQL error saying "field active can't be null".

```
{
    "Id":0,
    "Username":"TEST_POST",
    "FirstName":"POSTADO",
    "MiddleInitials":"API",
    "LastName":"PELO POSTMAN",
    "Password":"senha123",
    "Gender":"M",
    "Active":"N"
}
```

***(without Id information return the same error)***

But on a debug I saw that the parameter User (u) is null.

I can see it on ToString:

```
u   {[CollectionsCatalogWebAPI.Models.User: Username:  FirstName:  MiddleInitials:  LastName:  Gender:  Active: ]}
```

Some tip about this?

Comment: This is generated on post? If so you should decorate the input parameter with `[FromBody]` like `public IActionResult Post([FromBody]User u) {}`

Comment: As an FYI: you don't need any of those fields + properties. You could just use `public int Id { get; set; }` and remove those dozens of lines of code

Comment: @camilo I know about it. It was made just to seem more friendly for Java programmers (will be removed to build)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the `[FromBody]` like so:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]User u)
```

That way you bind data from the body of the request to `User` object

Comment: Thanks @kostis! It's works now! At this MS's doc it isn't informed: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: You are welcome! You can take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @JeanJ.Michel: It's not not required when you have `[ApiController]` on attribute on your controller (since ASP.NET Core 2.1) and **THIS IS** documented in the link you posted, you just have to read it, see the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#binding-source-parameter-inference section. `[ApiController]` is there for convinience for WebAPI-like controllers (that return xml or json data, instead of views that render into html)

Answer (score 1):

#### For the sake of competition:

Using of `[FromBody]` is not required when the controller is annotated with the `[ApiController]` Attribute (only supported in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and newer). It's a convenience method to reduce the number of required attributes on actions and action parameters.

Among other convenience methods, there is also a typed `ActionResult<T>` for WebAPI-esque actions and controllers.

You can get more information from the following blog post on [ASP.NET Core 2.1.0-preview1: Improvements for building Web APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-web-apis/)

> ### [ApiController] and ActionResult
>
> ASP.NET Core 2.1 introduces new Web API controller specific conventions that make Web API development more convenient. These conventions can be applied to a controller using the new `[ApiController]` attribute:
>
> - Automatically respond with a 400 when validation errors occur – no need to check the model state in your action method
> - Infer smarter defaults for action parameters: `[FromBody]` for complex types, `[FromRoute]` when possible, otherwise `[FromQuery]`
> - Require attribute routing – actions are not accessible by convention-based routes
>
> You can also now return ActionResult from your Web API actions, which allows you to return arbitrary action results or a specific return type (thanks to some clever use of implicit cast operators). Most Web API action methods have a specific return type, but also need to be able to return multiple different action results.

Comment: I notice now that my version of VS (2017 Enterprise) is using Core 2.0.x.
I'm looking for the correct way to update this now and take use of [ApiController] attribute, generics, etc.

Comment: Upgrade to the latest VS2017 version (15.7.5) as it should install the 2.1.302 SDK, which should also come with updated scaffolding tools and templates. Its worth even when you already have an existing project, especially if you are using ASP.NET Core Identity as the default views will be now in the identity assembly unless you want to customize these. Otherwise just updated the packages and csproj file to the new versions